# how could mapping a column to complex object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i want to design a column is text type
and use hibernate to convert to object
but the column is a bit difficult,it is liked `"1.5,2.32;4.2,53.2...."`
it represent many coordinate and is in order,(1.5,2.32),(4.2,53.2) and so on.
so i want to mappting the column to an object like

```
Public class Region{
  List<Coordinate> coordinateList;
}

public class Coordinate {
 double lat;
 double lng;
}
```

the coordinateList is the same as the column order such as (1.5,2.32),(4.2,53.2)
so how can i use annotion jpa or hibnernate annotation to convert the column to my defined object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to serialize and deserialize hibernate object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068663/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-hibernate-object)

Comment: Without using only one column, what is your problem if you define `Region` & `Coordinate` as Entity and do appropriate relationship from main/parent Entity ??? It will make your life easier for future manage & maintain on them.

Comment: but how can i get the order of many coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381765/when-usertype-represents-set-of-objects-in-single-line-how-to-query-hibernate-c). You need to implement a Hibernate UserType, which converts a specific SQL value to a custom Java type.

You could implement a similar SetStringType UserType, splitting string coordinates by comma and constructing Coordinate Java objects.